# Bi Publisher - Report with 2 different Datasources

Tags: report, bi-publisher

I have a Report that base on two different Datasoeurces. The Once is a sql-query with a parameter (in the WHERE clause) and the second is a XML-Data... Both (Parameter and XML-Data) I send over a httpRequest to the BI-Publisher. (I use the BI Webservice and use for the XML-Data the setReportData(byte[]) Method) and for the Parameter the setParameterNameValues(...) )... Now the problem is that the Publisher only use one of both. And only in my report are the values of the sql-query or the values of the XML-Data... So there is any solution to get all Vualues of both Datasources in my Report?

PLEASE can you help me? THANKS THANKS THANKS

Answer (score 0):

you can build a data template for your report. In the data template, you can specify as many different data source as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the output of the SQL-query as XML, into the XML-file that you already have. 
Ensure that the structure of the output is in sync with the existing XML structure.

And then, create a single report definition with data-source specified as XML-Data and run you report. This way - You will have both the data from the SQL-Query and the XML-data that you already have.